# Lubridate parse date warning

Tags: r, lubridate

I'm receiving warnings when I try to read `vector a` which contains many dates.

Here's the text file for `vector a` which I made using `write(a,"a.txt")`. As it's pretty big, I've attached it on Google drive for anyone to download. Basically, it contains the dates from 2012-01-01 to 2012-12-31, repeated many times.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B12dCpdCVHeSZjA4YmVXNmV6VUU/edit?usp=sharing

I tried to do this and received a warning message.

```
> head(ymd(a))
[1] "2012-01-01 UTC" "2012-01-01 UTC" "2012-01-01 UTC" "2012-01-01 UTC" "2012-01-01 UTC"
[6] "2012-01-01 UTC"
Warning message:
 7202 failed to parse.
```

Looking at the warning message, it would be easy to assume that the date format is wrong. However, YYYY-MM-DD is a format that is supported by lubridate. When I do the same to a part of the vector, nothing happens.

```
> head(ymd(a[1:50000]))
[1] "2012-01-01 UTC" "2012-01-01 UTC" "2012-01-01 UTC" "2012-01-01 UTC" "2012-01-01 UTC"
[6] "2012-01-01 UTC"
```

Using `strptime` and `as.Date` also doesn't produce any error

```
> head(strptime(a,format="%Y-%m-%d"))
[1] "2012-01-01" "2012-01-01" "2012-01-01" "2012-01-01" "2012-01-01" "2012-01-01"
> head(as.Date(a))
[1] "2012-01-01" "2012-01-01" "2012-01-01" "2012-01-01" "2012-01-01" "2012-01-01"
```

My question is, do I need to worry about the warning message or can I safely ignore it?

Comment: I am getting values like "2012-03-01(1)" from row number 122241 onwards. I don't know may be i am wrong but because of this may be you are getting a warning.

Answer (score 2):

```
> b <- which( is.na( ymd(as.character(a[[1]]), tz="UTC") ) )
Warning message:
 7202 failed to parse. 
> head(b)
[1] 122241 122242 122243 122244 122245 122246
> as.character(a[[1]])[head(b)]
[1] "2012-03-01(1)" "2012-03-01(1)" "2012-03-01(1)" "2012-03-01(1)" "2012-03-01(1)"
[6] "2012-03-01(1)"
```

Looks like there are strings of such anomalous dates separated by large gaps:

```
rle( diff(b) )
Run Length Encoding
  lengths: int [1:15] 1183 1 831 1 928 1 605 1 639 1 ...
  values : int [1:15] 1 111657 1 29857 1 26065 1 25111 1 65729 ...
```

Comment: This is a great answer, but it still would be nice if we could directly access the data causing the warning.

Answer (score 1):

Different solution using the anydate package, which seems to work.

```
library(anydate)
text <- anydate(a[, 1])
sum(is.na(text)) 

# 0
```